# how to apply different styles for angular bootstrap modals

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

In my application I've used angular bootstrap $modal to open a modal dialog. I've modified the styles given by the bootstrap to apply some transition to my modal dialog, but as I continue further in my application development we got the need to bring more modal windows, but we don't want to apply this transition to all the modal dialog. How can I do this. Apart from these styles I already have individual styles for each of the modals based on it's position on the screen and size of the modal window, for this I' using  windowClass: modalOptions.winClass property of the $modal.open method.

```
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
  transition: transform .10s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the answer in the question? Add the transition CSS styles based on the class of the modal, passed in modalOptions.windowClass.